# Unexpected JSon response from Spring Rest API Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a method in my Spring controller, in which I am returning an object containing a spring attribute with a value *"\HelloWorld"*. To store it into Java String object I have to put escape character, then the string becomes *"\\HelloWorld"*. When I print, that works totally fine and prints *"\HelloWorld"*. but when I return it in JSon response, it's returning *"\\HelloWorld"*.

But I want it to return *"\HelloWorld"*.

Bellow is the snippet:

```
   @RequestMapping("") 
    @ResponseBody
    public MyDataObject greeting() {
       MyDataObject f = new MyDataObject();
        f.setMessage("\\HelloWorld");
        return f;
    }
```

It's Json response is "message":"\\HelloWorld", but I want it "\HelloWorld".

Note: I don't want to unescape manually specific to that string.

Comment: `\\` character need to be escaped in JSON. If you want such output, consider a standalone string with plain text.

Comment: Yes I know I will have to write code to remove that, isn't there anything in Spring to unescape automatically ?
As if I return only String "\\HelloWorld" from my controller, instead of putting in controller. it's working fine and returning "\HelloWorld". Why's the case if I put string in MyObject attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as Jakson and it will internally handle such complexities.

```
MyDataObject f = new MyDataObject();
f.setMessage("\\HelloWorld");
String payload = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(params);
```

Comment: @RequestMapping("")
 @ResponseBody
 public String greeting() throws JsonProcessingException {
  MyObject f = new MyObject ();
  f.setMessage("\\HelloWorld");

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  return mapper.writeValueAsString(f);

 } and still returing double slashes

Comment: It's returning "message": "\\HelloWorld",